# Confusion about the method Object.prototype.valueOf()

Tags: javascript

I've recently read the article about [Object.prototype.valueOf() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and feel like they got something completely wrong by saying:

> The `valueOf()` method returns the primitive value of the specified object.

I mean, this sentence would make some sense if we were talking about the more specific versions of this method, for example `String.prototype.valueOf()`, which is closer in the prototype chain and therefore would be called instead of the `Object.prototype` method, when the `valueOf` method of a `String` object is invoked. In this case, the internal algorithm `thisStringValue` would be run and the value of the internal property `[[StringData]]` of the object, i.e. the primitive string value would be returned. So this would be indeed a conversion from object to primitive value.

But as far as I understand it, the `valueOf` method of `Object.prototype` works exactly the **opposite** way, by calling the internal method `ToObject`.

Now, if `Object.prototype.valueOf()` is called upon a plain object, it would invoke `ToObject` passing in the this value of the method, which points to the object itself, and in this case, `ToObject` would just return the reference on the object, which is displayed via `toString()` as `[object Object]`.

Supposed we would have overridden the value of `String.prototype.valueOf()` with the related method of `Object.prototype` for example and then create a `String` object by calling the constructor. - If we now invoke `valueOf()`, we would get an **object** in return and NOT the primitive string value we passed in as an argument. There's just `ToObject` in `Object.prototype.valueOf()`, no conversion from object to primitive value, as far as I see it.

So did I get this right and they're wrong, or is it me who didn't understand it?

Comment: Have you read on that page the small yellow ***Note***?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Just replace String.prototype.valueOf() with, say, Number.prototype.valueOf(). It's the same thing: If you create a Number object by calling the constructor with argument 5 and invoke the native valueOf() method, you get the number 5 as a primitive value. If you override the Number method with Object.prototype.valueOf(), you'll get an object as return value. Makes no difference.

Comment: If an object doesn't override this method in the prototype chain, its "primitive value" is simply the object itself.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your formatting and sorry for my bad english. ;-) Well, the point is in my eyes: If Object.prototype.valueOf() is invoked, there will just NEVER be a conversion to a "real" primitive value, because it is ToObject which is called and nothing else, so the return value will allways be an object, even if there was a primitive value, the argument could've been converted to.

Comment: You're not supposed to call `Object.prototype.valueOf()` directly. The point of this method is to provide something that a type can override. You're supposed to call `something.valueOf()` and it will invoke that object's method.

Comment: `Object.prototype.valueOf` is just there as a default for objects that don't override it.

Answer (score 2):

> The `valueOf()` method returns the primitive value of the specified object.

Remember, MDN is written by mere mortals such as you and I. I would not have chosen this way to summarize `valueOf`. A more meaningful summary would have been (borrowing from the "Description" below):

> The `valueOf()` method returns the value to be used when the specified object needs to be coerced to a primitive.

The rest of the description on the MDN page seems pretty reasonable and clear to me.

From your comment:

> I think it is wrong to treat all valueOf-methods of built-in objects as one, because they do not act the same way, which is implied in the article I linked in my question.

But the article itself says

> Every built-in core object overrides this method to return an appropriate value.

So it is **not** treating them all as one. Yes, there is one `valueOf` **interface**, but it has different implementations on different objects.

> it is wrong to say THIS method would be "called to convert an object to a primitive value"

I don't see that exact phrase in the article, but it sounds right to me.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `Object.prototype.valueOf` is just to serve as a default method for objects that don't override it with a more specific method. You shouldn't call this function directly, it's just called as a result of not having something more specific in the prototype chain when you call the `valueOf()` method of an object.

By definition, if an object doesn't override it, its "primitive value" is just the object itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I think about the purpose of this method, full ACK! And just for that reason I think it is wrong to treat all valueOf-methods of built-in objects as one, because they do not act the same way, which is implied in the article I linked in my question. The specific versions convert if possible to a primitive value, but the "default" version of `Object.prototype` will never do this. So, as I see it, it is wrong to say THIS method would be "called to convert an object to a primitive value", as done in thie article. - That's the point. ;-)

Comment: I think the problem is more with the organization of MDN. It doesn't have a place to document generic protocols, it just documents specific methods. But the explanation of how this method is used by the system is supposed to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not exactly accurate, and it is "more true" for specific implementations as you correctly said, but it is a summary and explains the intention of the method.

> it is wrong to say THIS method would be "called to convert an object to a primitive value",

No, it's correct. To be more precise: It's called to convert an object to a number. From the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive):

> When the abstract operation OrdinaryToPrimitive is called with arguments O and hint, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Assert: Type(O) is Object
> 2. Assert: Type(hint) is String and its value
>      is either "string" or "number".
> 3. If hint is "string", then Let
>      methodNames be «"toString", "valueOf"».
> 4. Else, Let methodNames be
>      «"valueOf", "toString"».
> 5. For each name in methodNames in List order, do
>
> ...
>
> iii. If Type(result) is **not** Object, return result.
>
> 6. Throw a TypeError exception.

There is no guarantee, of course, that an implementation of `valueOf` actually returns a primitive value, but that's what the method is for. And even `Object.prototype.valueOf` will in fact be called to convert an object to a primitive value, if there is no other implementation in the prototype chain. It won't work, as you noticed, but it will be called nonetheless.

You can try it yourself:

```js
var myObject = {
      valueOf: function() {
        console.log('valueOf');
        return this;
      },
      toString: function() {
        console.log('toString');
        return this;
      }
    };
 
1 + myObject;
```

Will print:

```
valueOf
toString
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```